# DELETE records without associated ones

Tags: sql, postgresql, t-sql, one-to-many, sql-delete

I have a 'guests' table and 'invitations' table bound with many-to-one relationship in a postgreSQL database. I have removed some guests and now I want to remove invitations that have no guests. I tried using 'COUNT', but aggregates are not allowed in WHERE clause.

Comment: Just wanted to address "aggregates are not allowed in WHERE clause" 
You would need to use COUNT in the HAVING clause instead of WHERE clause. WHERE filters rows before aggregation, HAVING filters after aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this :

```
delete from invitations where invitationid 
not in (select invitationid from guests)
```